# itunesConnect, Select an iOS version to test is not the latest version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

My connection was dropped while I am uploading the archive to the apps store.. and it showed Uploaded successfully with big green tick..

And also it goes to the app store and wait forever in the processing state. So I just uploaded it with the new build number and it's processed within less than 10 minutes.

but troubles are not over :(

then I couldn't select my latest build for test it still showed that stuck one..

What can I do for this ?

[image]

====================================================================

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the steps which I did to got build to the testflight internal testers

- to show Export Compliance add below line

to info.plist

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>
```

- change version no to different one (not the build no)
- create archive and upload it without upload bitcode enable tick

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me a few times already i.e. when a binary doesn't finish processing due to connection drop or other issues (on apple side).

Just upload a new build and use that build for release or test flight. Don't worry about the build that never finishes. Just ignore it and move on.

If you are still seeing build 2 as the latest under testfligth section, then logout, clear your browser cache, log back in and see. Clearly your build 3 is the latest one. itunesconnect is super flaky.

Use apple support as a last resort. They will take days to solve something as simple as this.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience when the build stays greyed out and (processing) for longer than a few minutes it will stay forever like that. Best to just re-upload and wait for the new build to process. It does take a bit of time to show up for testing though.